# Access Google Drive API from a Google Cloud function

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, jwt, google-cloud-functions

I've seen that there are different NodeJS modules that use Google APIs.
What's the best practice to access files that are shared with the service account of a Google Cloud function?

Answer (score 14):

I develop mainly with Python, but it has a similar problem as Node that you mentioned: lots of libraries & too many differing code samples out there. Another issue is that accessing Google Workspace (GWS; formerly G Suite APIs [like Drive]) is VERY different than GCP APIs.

A service account identity is the best way to access the [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive) from GCF. However, you can choose either a Cloud Function's [default service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#default) identity (same for an App Engine app), or as another answer here suggested, a [user-managed service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#user-managed) instead. The latter is a good idea if you're planning to have multiple identities that do different things, need differing types of access, etc., otherwise it's easier to use the default because you don't really have to do anything else other than create a private key-pair for that account.

Once you've decided on what type of service account, best to use the [Google APIs Client Library for Node.js](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client) to talk to Drive, G Suite, and other **non-GCP** Google APIs. Follow the [Drive API Node.js quickstart tutorial](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs) to learn how to "work it." Since Drive files typically belong to *user accounts* instead of *service accounts*, the auth example in the quickstart features [OAuth client ID (user account) auth](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#installed) rather than [service account auth](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#serviceaccount) to prompt the user (Drive owner) to give the app permission to access their data, so don't just cut-n-paste!

If you're **not** using Cloud Functions (or any GCP product), you're likely doing a web app or cmd-line tool. In *that* situation, you should pick user auth (OAuth client ID) instead of service acct auth so end-users on your website or running the cmd-line tool who are the [Drive file owners] *explicitly* grant permission via the familiar [OAuth consent dialog](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/gsuite-apis-intro/img/c2648f37bcb7a0c1.png) for *your* code to access *their* files. As the developer, you'd need to [setup that OAuth consent screen in the Cloud Console](http://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent) beforehand. NOTE: that screenshot was taken from my [Workspace APIs intro tutorial](http://g.co/codelabs/gsuite-apis-intro) [Python].

Copy the necessary boilerplate from the sample and replace the user acct auth with service account auth. See the [service account section of the Node.js client library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#service-account-credentials) docs on how to do it. Don't forget to create a private key-pair for whichever service account you decide to use from the [Service accounts page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts) and any roles/permissions it should have. It'll prompt you to download the key file once it's created, and then upload that w/your function (unless you use Secret Manager as suggested in another answer). By using client libraries, you avoid having to stick things in request headers (also as suggested in another answer). **However**, under no circumstances should you check that key file into Git if that's part of your CI/CD cycle; if your private key gets leaked/exposed publicly... DOOM shall befall you.

Comment: Thanks!
Can you please share an example of a background CF in python that acquires drive_service through its service account identity?

Comment: Good question but different than the OP here. I don't have an example now but suggest you create another SO question specially asking what you're *really* seeking, link to this question, and add any other details, like you want to call an event-driven CF based upon someone updating a file on Google Drive, i.e., https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes/watch. You sound like you know what you're doing & should be able to do it yourself given my hints above plus https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#using-the-keyfile-property

Answer (score 2):

The default behavior is as follows:

> During function execution, Cloud Functions uses the service account `PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` as its identity. For instance, when making requests to Google Cloud Platform services using the Google Cloud Client Libraries, Cloud Functions can automatically obtain and use tokens to authorize to the services this identity has permissions to use.

More information [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity).

---

Personal recommendation: it's good practice to use a [purpose-specific service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys) which you'll need to securely store & not push into your version control -- meaning you can download and include it in your `gcloud functions deploy` scripts (so it'll be readable to the nodeJS runtime along with `your package.json` and actual function files) -- but always have it git-ignored.

If you want to be super secure, you can combine this approach with another google cloud product called [Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs). The nodeJS implementation of which is [here](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-secret-manager/blob/master/samples/quickstart.js). The disadvantage of this, though, is the amount of time between the function start-up and the deciphering of the encrypted JSON (since it's a network operation itself.)

---

There is one more important thing to know -- the drive API token -- already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58842310/8160318.