# Google drive Authorization error while deploying a cloud function

Tags: python, authentication, google-api-python-client

I've hosted a cloud function on `abc@example.com` account which uploads a file to google drive folder.

But the google drive folder is on another google count `xyz@example.com`. I've given access of that folder to `abc@example.com`

But when I'm deploying the cloud function, in the logs its says `Please visit this URL to authorize this application **link**`.

I'm unable to authorize the cloud function using that link and it is redirecting to http://localhost:8000.

What am I missing here?

Comment: how are you generating the credentials for `abc@example.com`? Is this a service account? (Note, you should use [service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts) in server-based authentication requests, not a normal user account.)

Comment: @EdoAkse, I've used Service account's credentials and used auth-json file of that account.

Comment: See [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63164714/9267296) from a Googler